# Laravel 5: Eloquent whereHas subquery doesn't filter results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve some results from a model using a relation and I'm trying to apply some filters on that relationship.

Here is the model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProduct extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $table = "user_product";

    public $fillable = [
        ...
        "product_id",
        "user_id",
        "is_featured",
        "is_hidden_from_latest"
        ...
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\\App\\Models\\Product", "product_id", "id");
    }

    ...

}
```

and here is the related model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";

    public $timestamps = false;

    public $fillable = [
        ...
    ];

    public function userProduct()
    {
        return $this->hasOne("\\App\\Models\\UserProduct", "product_id", "id");
    }

    ...

}
```

Here is the query on `UserProduct` model and product relationship:

```
$user_products = UserProduct::with("product")
    ->whereHas("product", function($q) {
        $q->where("product_status", "live")
            ->where("parent_child", "Child");
    })->where("is_featured", 1)
        ->orWhere("is_hidden_from_latest", 0)
        ->orderBy("is_featured", "desc")
        ->orderBy("updated_at")
        ->get();
```

The problem is that `whereHas` subquery doesn't seem to filter anything no matter what value to compare to I use for each `product_status` and `parent_child`.

Is there something that I don't do correctly?

---

Update: Seems that the game breakers are these two `where()` statements at the end:

```
....
->where("is_featured", 1)
->orWhere("is_hidden_from_latest", 0)
....
```

and more specifically the `orWhere()` statement.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why your relationships have double backlash?

Comment: When using strings to define namespaces, [string escaping rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) may apply, so to avoid that it is recommended to use double backslashes.

Comment: Backslashe used for access namespaces, i dont understand why double.

Comment: Because including the namespaces in php as in many other languages which supports namespaces is done without quotes, but in this case I'm using a string to define the related Model, as in some cases backslashes may be escaped it is safer to use backslashes. It is not a requirement, though.

Comment: Did you solve this issue already?

Comment: @dacastro4 Yes, but I had to remove the `orWhere()` statement because if the condition inside `orWhere()` is true then the query builder just ignores previous statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$user_products = UserProduct::with("product")
->whereHas("product", function($q) {
    $q->where("product_status", "live")
    ->where("parent_child", "Child");
})
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where("is_featured", 1)
    ->orWhere("is_hidden_from_latest", 0);
})
->orderBy("is_featured")
->orderBy("updated_at")
->get();
```

Comment: wait, what are you filtering? UserProduct or Product?

Comment: I'm filtering UserProduct by the product relationship attributes values. The way I've done it initially is correct and as I specified in the question update it is the orWhere statement which breaks the filtering.

Comment: Tray again, please

Answer (score 0):

I just removed `where("is_featured", 1)` and replaced it with just `where("is_hidden_from_latest", 0)` as I order the results ascendantly by `is_featured` anyway.

The `whereHas()` subquery works properly. :)